# Running tee from alt+f2

Tags: tee

For some reason this works from term and does not from "run" dialogue or Openbox shortcuts...
`echo 200 | sudo tee /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably not working from the "run" dialogue because the `sudo` command prompts for a password -- but there's no terminal to enter it in!

Please try replacing the `sudo` with `gksudo`, so the line looks like this:

```
echo 200 | gksudo tee /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness
```

I *think* this should work... if not, try replacing the `gksudo` with `pkexec`.

Alternatively, you could put that line in a Bash script, and run your script with `gksudo myscript.sh` (replacing `myscript.sh` with the filename of your script). That way your entire script will run with superuser privileges, and it won't require the sudo password again.

Comment: entering a password each time i press a hotkey would be tiring. my sudo password is long ago disabled, however it still didn't work